# COUNTIF ? I need to count dates, but only once

Tags: if-statement, count, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

I have a sheet that has become complex, it has a lot of filters and I need to populate a table with data. I am counting how many times a month we run a product. If we run it once a day, or more, I want to only count that as one.

```
Date     Product   Grizzly
1/1      2.5       open
1/1      1.5       closed
1/1      2.5       closed
1/1      2.5       open
```

Something a little more elaborate than this, but what I need is to count this as one day of 2.5 grizzly closed, instead of two.

Any help? I feel like there is something simple I am missing but cant put my thumb on it and I have spent well over 15 hours working on this.

Answer (score 0):

As found on the following link:

[Link to Answer](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-count-one-occurrence.htm)

Try using the DCOUNTA function within Excel.

Although I'm also sure that you could use a pivot chart to provide the same outcome.

## EDIT:

I am assuming you are starting with data like the following:

[image: Start Data]

I then created the following table which you can extend to comply with you total data value. For example, you can add extra dates and products.:

[image: Step 2]

The table is populated using a COUNTIFS function.

```
=COUNTIFS("DateRange",DateCriteria, "ProductRange", ProductCriteria, "GrizzlyRange", GrizzlyCriteria)
```

So in my table the formula looks like this but the cell references will obviously changes according to your spreadsheet (I used absolute references to make it easier to use the fill handle to copy the formula down:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,$F$3,$C:$C,$F$2)
```

I next nestled this formula in to an IF statement and applied a conditional formatting to end up with the following:

[image: Step 3]

So the formula for each of the cells is now:

```
=IF("OriginalFormula),"Yes","No")
```

Example of my 01/01/2015, 1.5 open value:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$E4,$B:$B,$F$3,$C:$C,$F$2),"Yes","No")
```

BUT - You can change the "Yes" and "No" to "1" and "0" if you want to stick with numerical values.

Comment: I have a multitude of filters on the sheet, and maybe I am just too much of a novice, but how will this filter things I do not want out? I guess, what I am looking for is an example of how to write the equation in there.

Comment: That sounds more like you want to use a pivot table to display your data

Comment: I am completely inexperienced with pivot tables, can I transfer the data out of a pivot table to another table? What about a MACRO?

Comment: See my edited answer above. If I understand your question correctly that should suite your needs.